# Do you know some sites or resources to checking text for errors?

Tags: discussion

I need to write a texts every day and checking them for mistakes. I thought about some site where you can check others' textes for mistakes on your native language (russian), and others check your text. Thaks for the attention, and sorry for the REALLY BAD ENGLISH.

Comment: Hello. When you say "texts" are you refering to SMS type texts as would be sent from a phone? If so, there is a list here: https://androidappsforme.com/spell-check-apps-android/ Many are free, but some are for spelling checks only. For PC there are many here: https://www.doublemesh.com/best-free-grammar-checker/ then this one: https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/Windows-PC/Grammar-Check-Anywhere.html which can be used offline.

Comment: Thanks, duckisaduckisaduck. I didn't think, that someone will answer for this question.